# Always pipe a command with another command

Tags: shell-script, command-line, zsh

How can I do the following?

If a command looks like

```
git show .....
```

Then run

```
git show ..... | bat -l rs
```

I mean, add `| bat -l rs` to the end of command before running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
   show) git "$@" | bat -l rs ;;
   *) git "$@" ;;
esac
```

Then alias this script to `git`. If you want to run native `git show` use `\git` to escape the alias.

Or by defining a shell function and  using `command` and e.g. adding it to the shell rc-file (`bash`-syntax):

```
git() {
case "$1" in
   show) command git "$@" | bat -l rs ;;
   *) command git "$@" ;;
esac
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that overriding native `git` commands can play havoc with scripts and such; it's the same reason git aliases that hide existing commands [are silently ignored](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-alias).

However, if you define your script as a *new* git subcommand by naming it `git-something`, it will automatically be picked up by git. So, for example, creating an executable file `git-myshow` somewhere on the `PATH`, with the contents:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

git show "$@" | bat -l rs
```

Will let you run `git myshow <any show arguments>` and have it safely translated into `git show <any show arguments> | bat -l rs`. The name of the subcommand will be dependent on the name of the script (`git-showit`  == `git showit`, etc.), so you can choose whatever you like as long as it's not the same as an existing subcommand.

Comment: Overriding a `git` command with an ordinary shell function would have no impact on any script.

Answer (score 2):

#### Different pager for a Git subcommand

You can configure Git to use a [different pager for different subcommands](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pagerltcmdgt). If you specifically want to use `bat -l rs` for `git show` but not for other Git commands:

```
git config pager.show 'bat -l rs'
```

Or equivalently, put the following in your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[pager]
show = bat -l rs
```

Note that if you set the `GIT_PAGER` environment variable, it applies to all Git subcommands.

#### Define a new Git subcommand

Git itself has an alias system. You can't override built-in commands, but you can define your own. For example, put this in your `~/.gitconfig` to make `git sb` equivalent to `git show` except that it goes through Bat.

```
[alias]
sb = ! "f () { git show \"$@\" | bat -l rs; }; f"
```

Beware that `git sb` will return 0 even if `git show` fails. To avoid this, you need to rely on a different shell such as bash or zsh.

```
[alias]
sb = ! "zsh -c 'setopt pipe_fail; f () { git show \"$@\" | bat -l rs; }; f'"
```

#### Parsing the command in the shell

It's not particularly convenient compared to Git's built-in features, but it can be done. Define a function called `git`, and make it parse its arguments. This can be very flexible, but the first step is to parse the Git command line. It's easy to check whether the first *argument* is `show`, but harder to check that the first *non-option argument* is `show`. Here's a function that does this, assuming the format of `git --help` doesn't change too much.

```
git () {
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt pipe_fail
  local -A options_with_argument
  options_with_argument=()
  help="${$(command git --help)%%$'\n\n'*}"
  while [[ $help =~ \\[(-[A-Za-z0-9]\ \<|--[-A-Za-z0-9]+=) ]]; do
    local option=${${MATCH%%[= ]*}#'['}
    options_with_argument[$option]=1
    help=${help:$MEND}
  done
  local i=1
  while [[ $@[$i] = -* ]]; do
    if [[ -v options_with_argument[$@[$i]] ]]; then ((++i)); fi
    ((++i))
  done
  case $@[$i] in
    show) command git "$@" | bat -r ls;;
    *) command git "$@";;
  esac
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a wrapper script or function to do that.  Run the function or script **instead of** `git show`.  For example:

```
batshow () {
  git show "$@" | bat -l rs
}
```

If you write it as a script, make it executable and put it in your PATH - e.g. `~/bin`/ or `/usr/local/bin/`.

If you write it as a function, edit your `~/.zshrc` and add the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a shell function to do that:

```bash
git-show() {
     git show $1 | bat -l rs
}
```

Just add that to your shell config, and run `git-show` (instead of `git show`) and you'll have the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Bat appears to be a 'screen pager' program.  The more commonly known examples would be the programs named 'more' and 'less'.

Configuring the pager that your local git command will use is a popular topic, with a search for 'git pager config' returning lots of examples.  Here is one of them: https://waylonwalker.com/til/git-pager/ - it even has an example config that uses bat.

Comment: Can a pager be set to a _specific_ `git` subcommand though?

Comment: This I don't know.  I suggested putting the pager into the git config so git could intelligently decide when to use the pager and when to not use it.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, see my answer.